# Why does this Monkey test log "null"?

Tags: android, monkey

When I run this instruction in a Android TV adb shell

`monkey --ignore-crashes --ignore-timeouts --ignore-native-crashes --pct-touch 0 -v -v -v --throttle 50 -s 30 500000 >/data/local/tmp/monkeylog/test_3v_500k.txt 2>/data/local/tmp/monkeylog/test_3v_2_500k.txt &`

the TV stopped the tests and in the end of file test_3v_500k.txt prints null after several hours.

the beginning content of test_3v_500k.txt:
[the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiY1H.png)

the end of content of test_3v_500k.txt:
[the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knmyd.png)

And I want to know why the Monkey stopped and printed "NULL"

Comment: Looks buggy, I would try running it with different options (throttle off etc) to see in what circumstances it does and doesn't

Comment: Will it be the reason why I set too large count?

Comment: Maybe? try it. Rather than asking here first.